Can i use a metal gear servo motor to lift a 4kg load and then attach it to an actuator?
I am doing a project if which i am trying to resemble some muscle movements of an arm and i want to attach an actuator to a motor. But i don't know if a metal gear servo motor can lift that much load. The arm weighs almost 4-4.5kg

what does the spec sheet say?

And what is the load? So mass of arm plus load = total load...

motors can lift almost anything if they are geared right

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
